# Unity - непонятная ошибка при билде проекта

Tags: unity3d, build

При билде возникает такая ошибка:

```
The type or namespace name 'AssetDatabase' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Я посмотрел в инете, и это не связано с `using` в начале скрипта, как тогда можно это решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `AssetDatabase` размещен в пространство имен `UnityEditor`. А это пространство имен **доступно только в редакторе**. Соответственно, при компиляции это работать не будет.

Везде, где у Вас используются классы этого пространства, ровно как и само подключение к пространству имен, - необходимо "обернуть" директивой прерпроцессора `#if`

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

<...>

#if UNITY_EDITOR
AssetDatabase.<...>
#endif
```